# Allow only specific file to run PHP via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

The following makes the list of extensions capable of executing PHP:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php5
```

How do I allow *only one specific file* to be able to run PHP?

The following does not work:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 example\.php9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not add filename to `AddType` directive. Only file extensions are allowed. To add php handler to a single file you can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^thisfile\.php$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php5]
```

Or `<filesMatch>`

```
<filesMatch "^thisfile\.php$">
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
</filesMatch>
```

Reference :

Mod-rewrite flags

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_h

filesMatch

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Answer (score 0):

You should use rewrite rule in htaccess.

```
 RewriteRule ^example\.php9/?$ exmaple.php
```